# How do I release a blocked sudo user

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

I use a centos instance for a production system. I do not know how But the root password was enabled or centos user was removed from sudoers. Before I was able to run sudo commands or even run sudo su without password prompt But now it is blocked.

Can any one suggest how to resolve it? I also cannot restart the instance as there is an important system running on it.

I am quite desperate. The centos is version 7.5

Comment: Can you login as root?

Answer (score 0):

One of the above things happened here.

**CASES :**

1- You have been removed from sudoers.

2- A password directive have been added to sudoers for security enforcement.

So i suggest you to execute the command with **sudo** as you are doing frequently, when it prompts you for a password, enter yours :

If you have something like : *user is not in the sudoers file*. Then you have been removed from sudoers so you have to contact the administrator. **CASE 1**

If it does work, it's fine. **CASE 2**